# why printf('c') cause Segmentation fault?

Tags: gcc-warning

This is my test code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf('c');
    return 0;
}
```

**SO:** ubuntu16.04

**Compiler version:** gcc5.3

Running the code above cause Segmentation fault error in "movdqu (%rdi),%xmm0 ".

I had google it, but I want to know why cause Segmentation fault

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/9470239/1647238, it's for C but maybe also applies

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to pring a char, not a string. First argument of printf() function is a format string.
Strings are quoted in "", chars in ''.

Comment: Thanks.I know print("c") is right. The detail in Segmentation fault  is Illegal access to memory? I just want to know

Comment: @kaiattrib The argument to printf is an address. printf is interpreting the character as an address outside of what the program is allowed to access.

Answer (score 0):

I fond the error when use GDB debug the  program.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrSEv.png)

Comment: I honestly don't understand at all this thing of posting links to pictures of text. Also: not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

### SHORT:

This is prototype of `printf` function in C:

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

You should pass c-string (like "this is my message") instead of `char`.

### DETAILED:

This is prototype of `printf` function in C:

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

This means that the first argument should be a pointer to a null-terminated array of `char`. In fact, `printf` reads value of first argument which is address of an c-string in memory, then go to that address and reads bytes by bytes to reach null character. In two condition this code causes segmentation fault:

1. The address is pointed by the first argument of `printf` is outbound of memory address of your program.
2. `printf` can't find any null characters beginning from the specified address before reaching end of memory boundary of your program.

Please be careful about using non-pointer variables in place of pointers. This cause your program to crash without a argumentive reason.